# How to fetch td value which checkbox is checked in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I use table.

My html code is :

```
 <table id="assTB" border="1px" cellspacing="0">
       <colgroup>
       <col style="width:15%">
       <col style="width:15%">
       <col style="width:70%">
       </colgroup>
       <tbody>
       <tr style="height:35px">
      <td   bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b><input type="checkbox" id="assCB"></b></td>
       <td   bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b>id</b></td>
       <td   bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b>name</b></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tr>
       <td><b><input type='checkbox'></b></td>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Tom</td>
       </tr>    
       <tr>
       <td><b><input type='checkbox'></b></td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>John</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="selAtt()">
```

My js code is:

```
function selAtt()
{
    var xzyId=document.getElementById("assTB");//tableID
    var checked=xzyId.getElementsByTagName("input");//checkbox


    var names = [];

    for(i=1;i<checked.length;i++)
    {
      if(checked[i].checked)
      {
        //rete=checked[i].parentNode.parentNode;//works fail
        //rete=checked[i].closest("tr");//works fail
        //rete=checked[i].parent().prev();//works fail
        rete = checked[i].parent().prev();//works fail
        var stNum=rete.find("td:eq(2)").text();
        names.push(stNum);
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        alert(names[i]);
    }
    }
}
```

Now I want to fetch name when checkbox is checked in the same row.

I have tried four methods to fetch rete as in above code.

But unlucky, they are all fail. Who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use map() to add in array
2. Use :checked to select only checked checkbox
3. Use :nth-child to get the desired td (:nth-child index starts with 1)

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var arr = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var obj = {};

    obj['id'] = tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    obj['name'] = tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

    return obj;
  }).get();
  console.log(arr)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="assTB" border="1px" cellspacing="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:70%">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height:35px">
      <td bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b><input type="checkbox" id="assCB"></b></td>
      <td bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b>id</b></td>
      <td bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b>name</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><b><input type='checkbox'></b></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><input type='checkbox'></b></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="button" id="button">
```

For name only :

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var arr = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    return tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
  }).get();
  console.log(arr)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="assTB" border="1px" cellspacing="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:70%">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height:35px">
      <td bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b><input type="checkbox" id="assCB"></b></td>
      <td bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b>id</b></td>
      <td bgcolor="#CDCDCD"><b>name</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><b><input type='checkbox'></b></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><input type='checkbox'></b></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>John</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="button" id="button">
```